# Группирование по N строк и суммирование

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

Имеется Excel с данными: ID Period (время) и значение к примеру D.

Tаблицу отсортировал как нужно, вот код:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel("C:\\...\\primer.xlsx")

table = pd.pivot_table (data, index="period", columns="id", fill_value=0)
```

Далее хочу выбрать `period` он в строку идет, там 1000+ строк, хочу разделить его к примеру на 5 или 10:

```py
table["period"] = int[(table["period"]/5)*5]

print(table)
```

И тут ничего не выходит, вываливается ошибка о том, что не понимает, что такое `Period`.

Необходимо 1000+ строк разделить на 5, причем просуммировать значение с 0 по 5, с 5 по 10 и т.д. (просуммировать каждые 5 строк по порядку), ну и в конце вывести такую же матрицу, только в 5 раз меньше по строкам, столбцы остаются как есть. Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Пример водных данных. 
Цветом выделил те 5 строк, которые нужно просуммировать и в итоге получить вместо 25 строк, только 5 строк.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20*3).reshape(-1, 3), columns=list("abc"))

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
     a   b   c
0    0   1   2
1    3   4   5
2    6   7   8
3    9  10  11
4   12  13  14
5   15  16  17
6   18  19  20
7   21  22  23
8   24  25  26
9   27  28  29
10  30  31  32
11  33  34  35
12  36  37  38
13  39  40  41
14  42  43  44
15  45  46  47
16  48  49  50
17  51  52  53
18  54  55  56
19  57  58  59
```

группируем по три строки:

```
In [7]: res = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3).sum()
```

результат:

```
In [8]: res
Out[8]:
     a    b    c
0    9   12   15
1   36   39   42
2   63   66   69
3   90   93   96
4  117  120  123
5  144  147  150
6  111  113  115
```

Comment: идиотский вопрос, но быстро ответа не нашел. вот мы сделали groupby. А как увидеть результат группировки, скажем в виде таблицы с двухуровневым индексом, если я не хочу никаких агрегатных функций применять

Comment: @splash58, как-то так: `grp = df.groupby(...); for i,x in grp: print(i, x)`

Comment: Ага. Спасибо! получилось

Comment: Спасибо огромное, получилось))

Comment: @MaxU а превратить groupby object в дата фрейм? только вот такое накопал `df.set_index([np.arange(len(df)) // 3, df.index])` а прямого пути не нашел, или его и нет?

Comment: @splash58, это зависит от того что вы хотите получить на выходе... Лучше задать отдельный вопрос с небольшими примерами входных и выходных данных